# What Windows 10 setting or application can show the wifi band being used (2.4 or 5 ghz) in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10

What Windows 10 setting or application can show the wifi band being used (2.4 or 5 ghz) in the taskbar when it's connected to wifi?

Basically... like where you see the wifi icon, with a 2.4 or 5 next it showing the active band.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The icon will show that wireless is connected and then look at the connected icon properties to see what it is connected to.

There is (normally) only one wireless connection and the icon will show you that connection.
I set up SSIDs to relate Band to connection.

If the SSID does not provide the information, you need to log into the router to see who is connected to what band.

It is easier for me to label the SSID informatively.

[image: System Tray Network Connection]

.

The way described above (putting the identifier in the Router) works with devices like my iPhone and Raspberry Pi as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nirsoft [WifiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) will tell you the band but with without adding the info in the taskbar.